# Identifying and replacing a lens of a 360° Giroptic camera (360cam)

Tags: optics

I broke a lens of a Giroptic 360cam. It is discontinued by the manufacturer and even the company does not exist anymore.

[Here is a link from the internet archive.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180214105623/https://www.giroptic.com/intl/360cam)

All the tech specs I found is those:

3x 185°, F/1.8

Is this enough to get a replacement? Maybe from any eye-optics shop? Or does anyone know which lens they used?

Photo: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zGQA.jpg)
Specs: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqOp2.png)

Comment: Maybe, was not sure, can it be migrated?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better suited to SE Photography

Answer (score 1):

As a mininum you would also need the focal length, or the sensor size behind the lens.

However, tech specs such as this are likely not accurate enough. These lenses introduce quite acute distortions that have to be taken in account when stitching the images from the three lenses, and their characteristics are likely hardwired in the camera firmware, so you would have to find a lens with the very same distortions. Given what you know, not too likely. You best bet is to find a second hand broken camera as a source of spare parts.

Comment: Or buy a working second hand camera and use the original as a source of spare parts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all three lenses are supposed to be identical, it may be possible to get an optician to measure one of the two still-intact lenses and give you the more complete specifications you need. They might know of a company who could make a "clone" for you, though that would likely be more expensive than the camera is worth. Even if they can't make one for you, the specifications might make it possible to find one offered somewhere else. At least you'll know what to look for. Whoever supplied these lenses to the manufacturer probably offered the same lenses to anyone else willing to buy them.

Comment: I guess I have to disassemble / remove the lens?  Or is it possible to measure from outside?  Because I don't have a clue how remove it, seems glued in...